# Some users are on a free lifetime plan. Should I create a free product in the payment gateway or keep their data outside?

Tags: architecture, authorization, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

When we first established our product, we did a crowdfunding and certain early customers purchased a "lifetime subscription". Also sometimes we give a free lifetime accounts away, commonly to new members of our team and also to new business partners.

For everyone else, when they sign up for our service a record is created in the payment gateway, so John Smith signing up for the $100/year bronze plan, will have a customer record and a subscription linked to the bronze plan recorded in the Payment Gateway's admin portal.

My question is; for these lifetime free plans is it better to:

A) Handle them in my code so they never have a record added in the payment gateway; or

B) Add all these people in the payment gateway and link them up to say Lifetime Free Plan $0. Which simplifies authorisation checking code as I just check if they have a record in the payment gateway.

What is the better approach and why? Keep all customer records together in the payment gateway service or handle free lifetime plans outside of the payment gateway?

(FYI I've previously configured Stripe as a payment gateway and now and shifting to Chargebee for additional subscription management services, either way it's the same question I'm being faced with.)

Answer (score 3):

Since the question is very subjective. My opinion would be to have them included in the same plan that you have already based on the features you have provided to these lifetime customers.

There are two options here.

- Have them included in the Bronze Plan and give 100 % discount under offer code.
- Create a new plan with features assigned to these users and give 100 % discount for that plan.

In both the above options I would renew the subscriptions every year and generate a receipt for the transaction. There are multiple reasons I would do this.

- We would have a record of all the users and their transactions without coding specifically for these scenarios.
- Having a discount feature can be later used for other customers, thus adding a new feature in your product.
- You will get the exact amount you are spending on lifetime customers to date in your analytics, thus giving you a clear picture of funds spent and discounts given.

Again I would say this is my personal opinion, there may be other solutions to this as well.